# How to connect five flex sensors to on esp8266?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, flex

I’m using a lolin nodemcu 8266. I was wondering if it is possible to connect 5 flex sensors to one node (to make a glove which detects finger gestures).

I’m an experienced programmer but new to electronics.

Comment: Are they digital or analog output?

Comment: The ESP8266 typically has one analog input, so you'd need an analog mux, or more simply perhaps, an ADC with it's own analog mux.  Places like Adafruit sell various little multi-input ADC boards intended for use with the raspberry pi which lacks any ADC at all, that might fit your need.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I just started learning about electronics. Do you have a suggestion on one you would use ?